# Oracle: How to find non-local (background) processes in Windows Machine

Tags: oracle, windows

Following [link](http://dbacatalog.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/ora-01012-not-logged-on/) advises to find non-local background processes and kill them using following bash script.

> Solution 1) : without shutdown anything just kill that database
>   processes which are not local processes. local means background
>   processes.

```
ps -ef | grep $ORACLE_SID | grep -v grep | grep "LOCAL=NO" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

I read this script as.

1. ps -ef ,find all processs
2. pipe it to grep
3. filter $ORACLE_SID, that is find $ORACLE_SID lines, pipe it
4. filter out grep's line
5. filter "LOCAL=NO"
6. use awk to print column 2, that is process id
7. use xargs kill command to kill this processes.

This solution obviously in linux/unix since it uses the fact that "Oracle uses process architecture in linux/unix" and bunch of other unix commands. But Oracle in windows uses thread architecture.

Is there any equivalent in Windows Box, graphical or otherwise? I am aware of Process Explorer and I will look into it. But I wanted to ask here first.

To re-iterate I am not asking how to kill in windows box ([orakill](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_orakill.htm)) but how to find session/thread in Windows using command line tools without logging in database so that I can use orakill.